# Google Charts - Get a specific value

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a series of values plotted on a Line Chart. These values are inputs, from a user, via a HTML form.

Example 1 values :
130, 136, 142, 148, **149**, 159.

Example 2 values :
130, 140, **150**, 175, 180, 200.

Is it possible to have a script that can select the value that precedes the biggest increase?

So for example 1 - the value of interest would be **149** - because 149 to 159 is the biggest increase, value to value.

And for example 2 - the value of interest would be 150 - for the same reason.

Please advise.

Here is my code with your help so far :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
    url : "includes/dataFile.php",
    dataType : "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages' : ['corechart', 'line']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() { drawChart(data); });
        }
});

function drawChart(caldata) {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(caldata);
    data.addColumn('number', '');
    data.addColumn('number', '');
    data.addColumn('number', '');

    var dataArray = [];

    $.each(caldata, function(i, obj) {
        dataArray.push([parseFloat(obj.stage1_rate), parseInt(obj.stage1), parseInt(obj.stage1_duration)]);
        dataArray.push([parseFloat(obj.stage2_rate), parseInt(obj.stage2), parseInt(obj.stage2_duration)]);
        dataArray.push([parseFloat(obj.stage3_rate), parseInt(obj.stage3), parseInt(obj.stage3_duration)]);
        dataArray.push([parseFloat(obj.stage4_rate), parseInt(obj.stage4), parseInt(obj.stage4_duration)]);
        dataArray.push([parseFloat(obj.stage5_rate), parseInt(obj.stage5), parseInt(obj.stage5_duration)]);
        dataArray.push([parseFloat(obj.stage6_rate), parseInt(obj.stage6), parseInt(obj.stage6_duration)]);
        });

    data.addRows(dataArray);

    var linechart_options = {
         .....
    };

    var linechart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_div'));
    linechart.draw(data, linechart_options);

    function getMaxDelta(array) {
          return array[array.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
              return aa[r + 1] - aa[r] < aa[i + 1] - a ? i : r;
          }, 0)];
      }
      console.log(getMaxDelta([130, 136, 142, 148, 149, 159]));
    }
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the index with the greatest delta with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and check if the actual value and the following item is greater than the saved pair.

```js
function getMaxDelta(array) {
    return array[array.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        return aa[r + 1] - aa[r] < aa[i + 1] - a ? i : r;
    }, 0)];
}

var array1 = [130, 136, 142, 148, 149, 159],
    array2 = [130, 140, 150, 175, 180, 200];

console.log([array1, array2].map(getMaxDelta));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: But how do I get this line : console.log(getMaxDelta([130, 136, 142, 148, 149, 159])); to hold the parsed variables? For example : console.log(getMaxDelta([(input1), (input2), (input3), (input4), (input5), (input6)]));

Comment: are the inputs arrays?

Comment: Yes - parsed from a JSON data file

Comment: I've just edited the original question - adding the code I have and including your bit too.